# Can't see numbers in ol li list

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, html-lists

I have some numbered lists on a website with a wordpress template I'm currently developing. However, I can't see the numbers before numbered lists.

I've set `list-style-type: decimal` for ol > li and tried some other things, but none seemed to work.

Can somebody help me? (It's probably a really obvious mistake, but I've no more ideas how to do this)

Thanks!

[Example page](http://goo.gl/VCB77P)

Comment: Well first off you are missing the semicolon. Try adding it:

`list-style-type: decimal;`

Comment: @Darrell the semicolon is not always required. For example, both of the following are valid: `<ol style="list-style-type: decimal">` and `ol { color: red; list-style-type: decimal }`. But you are correct in the assumption that it could be the culprit if it came before other properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not set the `list-style-type` on the individual `li`'s but on the containing `ol` or `ul`.

In your CSS, you are setting this:

```
.wrapper .entry-content ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You are also resetting the padding further down in your CSS when the list-style will need 25px of padding to the left.

Try this:

```
.wrapper .entry-content ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: The `padding` and `margin` on `ol` and `li` are the actual point. Those hide the numbers on the left side.

Comment: Stewartside Great, it works. Thank you very much!
@Xufox Thanks, I've still got some things to learn..!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
ul {        
 list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: This was flagged as low quality content by SO users. Please edit this answer and explain it better to avoid down votes/deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `list-style-type: decimal !important;`
Please ***Use this sparingly.***

Comment: Not going to downvote but I'm of the position that `!important` should be used mostly as a last resort.

Comment: Of course it does, doesn't mean you should use it whenever you feel like it. Imagine if every selector in you stylesheet contained 10 IDs or all the properties had `!important` declared on them. How much fun would it be to update or extend the styles in the future?

Comment: that would also be a factor, but well, ok. I agree.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is there should be a warning with answers that suggest the use of `!mportant`, imho. They work, though I feel the pitfalls of using such a solution should be pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You've turned then off here

```
.wrapper .entry-content ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

You need to turn them back on.

```
.wrapper .entry-content ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. I totally missed his link in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little Test Page:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li>ul no style</li>
   <li>test</li>
  </ul></br>
  <ul style="list-style-type: decimal">
   <li>ul with style</li>
   <li>test</li>
  </ul></br>
  <ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
   <li>ol with style</li>
   <li>test</li>
  </ol></br>
  <ol>
   <li>ol without style</li>
   <li>test</li>
  </ol>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see setting the style for an `ordered list` is unnecessary.

If you want the numbers you can just *NOT* include the style and use the `<ol></ol>` tags.